# .htaccess redirect query to url

Tags: php, .htaccess

so I have a php query url like so
https://domain.tld/dl.php?device=dumpling
now I would like to be able to go on a nicer url like below to also redirect at same url as above
https://domain.tld/dl/dumpling

so by accessing both urls, would get same page
I know this is possible via apache .htaccess yet can't seem to figure out the proper values there
what I tried so far is

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^/?dl/(.*?)/?$ /dl.php?device=$1 [L]  
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /dl\.php\?device=([^\&\ ]+)  
RewriteRule ^/?dl\.php$ /dl/%1? [L,R=301]
```

Now by accessing https://domain.tld/dl.php?device=dumpling I do get redirected to https://domain.tld/dl/dumpling, however this returns a 404 page
Think it tries to go on /dl/dumpling folder that is indeed missing
I want only https://domain.tld/dl/dumpling to work and also return my query

What the heck am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Then you need to figure out why the first mapping rule doesn't work. Enabling the RewriteLog would help.

Comment: RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/$ /$1.php?device=$2 [NC,L]